# Is it possible to take folder "Shared with me" and use it as a "Shared drive"?

Tags: google-drive, mac, google-drive-shared-folder

Someone has shared a folder chock full of stuff with me. I would like to view its contents on my file system like a shared drive, rather than having to download items one by one from the web page.

Is there a way to use a folder "Shared with me" as a shared drive? Or am I stuck using the web app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the Google Drive feature to automatically download all the files in the folder shared with you on your computer, use **Google Drive for Desktop**.

1. Go to https://drive.google.com
2. Click the Settings button, then Get **Drive for Desktop**
   This will take you to a page showing a button to download **Google Drive for Desktop**.
3. Follow the instructions.
   This should guide you in downloading and installing **Google Drive for Desktop**.
4. To see the shared folder with you on **Google Drive for Desktop**, you might first have to create a file/folder shortcut on **My Drive** using the Google Drive *web app*. To do this,

   1. Open **Shared with me**.
   2. If needed, search or scroll until you see the *shared folder*.
   3. Right-click the *shared folder*, then **Organize** > Add **shortcut**.
5. Open the Google Drive location for your account using **Finder** or **Google Drive for Desktop**, then open **My Drive**.
6. You might right-click the folder corresponding to the shared folder with you and select **Available Offline**. This will download all the files included in the shared folder to your computer.
   Note: If your computer hasn't enough free storage space Google Drive will show a message.

---

**Shared Drive** is a term that might be confusing as it has multiple meanings. This term might refer to

- a Google Drive feature for **Google Workspace** accounts.
- a file storage item shared using a network protocol like SMB.

Comment: Short form: using the web interface, create a shortcut in My Drive that points to the drive that was shared with me. Give the Google Drive app a minute to sync up, and the shared folder appears as a symlink under My Drive in your file system.